# How To Protect Mobile Internet Access?

Tags: security, networking

I want to know how to protect mobile data connection function in Android. I don't want somebody or me accidentally switching it on.

I need something like **[Smart AppLock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&hl=en)** but to protect basic phone functions that control mobile data internet communication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your mobile network operator one solution could be to change the APN of your mobile network connection to an invalid value. On most mobile networks you don't get a data connection without a valid APN - however on some you always get a connection independently of the APN name.

There are plenty of tools that simplify APN setting/removing/changing - some examples:

- [APN On/Off](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.curvefish.widgets.apnonoff&feature=search_result)
- [APN Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=ale.android.apnmanager&feature=search_result)
- [APNDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro&feature=search_result)

Comment: Can i turn off APN temporarily?

Comment: Also can i set password?

Comment: @Boris_yo: Of course you can not set a password. Apps managing APNs simply automate what is available in the settings dialog - which is accessible by everyone. Therefore a password does not much sense.

Comment: Not good. I wanted something that would deny access to internet through mobile network in case somebody gets their hands on my device.

Comment: Then you should use the flight mode and disable the mobile network completely. The SIM PIN is a good protection.